How to Download YouTube Videos in 1080p with English Subtitles Using yt-dlp with Python 3
I am trying to download YouTube videos using yt-dlp in Python 3.9. I want to download videos in 1080p quality and if 1080p is not available, it should download the best available quality. The audio and video files should be merged into a single MP4 file, and I have ffmpeg installed to handle the merging process.
Here is my script:
import os
import sys
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

def download_video(url):
    output_dir = r"/path"  # Update this path

    # Ensure the output directory exists
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)
    
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': '(bestvideo[height<=1080][ext=mp4]/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best',
        'merge_output_format': 'mp4',
        'write_auto_sub': True,
        'writesubtitles': True,
        'subtitleslangs': ['en'],
        'subtitlesformat': 'vtt',
        'embedsubtitles': True,
        'outtmpl': os.path.join(output_dir, '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegVideoConvertor',
            'preferedformat': 'mp4',
        }],
    }

    with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python download_video.py <YouTube_URL>")
        sys.exit(1)

    youtube_url = sys.argv[1]
    download_video(youtube_url)

This script successfully downloads the video in 1080p quality or the best available quality and merges the audio and video files as intended. However, it does not download the subtitles as intended.
I have ffmpeg installed for merging the video and audio files. How can I modify this script to ensure that English subtitles are downloaded and embedded in the video file?

Hi, thanks for the reply and your efforts in trying to help. I Couldn't get the subtitles to be downloaded to begin with

Is it possible that the video you are trying to download does not have automatically created subtitles? If the video only has manually created subtitles, you will need to pass writesubtitles: True as part of the ydl_opts dictionary.

Hi, I have updated it, but still does not seem to work as intended. I still cannot get the subtitles to be downloaded I check that the youtube  vide does have subtitles but it is not being installed.
